# How to disable a html subtraction button when the value is 0?

Tags: javascript, html, css, button

So I've tried all over the internet for an answer and have been unable to come up with the correct answer.
My code:

HTML

```
<th scope="col">
  <button class="button" type="button" id="subButton"
   onclick="subStrength();" value="subtract">-</button>
</th>
<th>
  <span id="strength"></span>
</th>
```

JS:

```
function subStrength(){
  strength = strength - 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;
}

function addStrength(){
  strength = strength + 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach to this would be to call the `setAttribute()` or `removeAttribute()` methods on the button element to toggle the disabled/enabled state of the button depending on the value of the `strength` variable:

```js
var strength = 0;

document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;

function updateButtonDisabled() {

  // If strength less than equal zero disable the button
  if(strength <= 0) {
    document.getElementById("subButton").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("subButton").removeAttribute('disabled');
  }
}

function subStrength(){
  strength = strength - 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;
  
  updateButtonDisabled();
}

function addStrength(){
  strength = strength + 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;
  
  updateButtonDisabled();
}
```

```html
<th scope="col">
  <button class="button" type="button" id="subButton"
   onclick="subStrength();" value="subtract">-</button>
</th>
<th>
  <span id="strength"></span>
</th>
<th scope="col">
  <button class="button" type="button"
   onclick="addStrength();" value="add">+</button>
</th>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This has been incredibly helpful and solved my problem. Now it's just a matter of rearranging it to have the value in the centre.

Comment: @Mr.Student.exe you're welcome - just a moment, I'll update the answer to show how that can be done

Comment: @Mr.Student.exe does that help?

Comment: Oh yeah, it did, only problem I'm facing is converting it to other attributes, like agility. It displays NaN. Any help there?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do:

```
if (strength === 0) {
  document.getElementById('subButton').disabled = true;
}
```

in subStrength.

Just make sure to set disabled = false if strength > 0 in addStrength!

Answer (score 0):

First you need to have a default value for the strength. Here is my working code :

```js
strength = 5;
 function subStrength(){
  if(strength>0){
   strength = strength - 1;
     document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;
   if(strength==0){
    document.getElementById("subButton").disabled = true;
   }
  }
  
   
 }

 function addStrength(){
  strength = strength + 1;
  document.getElementById("strength").innerHTML = strength;
  if(strength>0){
   document.getElementById("subButton").disabled = false;
  }
 }
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
   <tr>
    
    <th scope="col">
      <button class="button" type="button" id="subButton"
       onclick="subStrength();" value="subtract">-</button>
    </th>
    <th scope="col">
      <button class="button" type="button"
       onclick="addStrength();" value="add">+</button>
    </th>
    <th>
      <span id="strength"></span>
    </th>

   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   
  </tbody>
 </table>
```